# Create a dynamic growing list in Manipulate from data obtained by URLExcecute of API

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, dynamic

I have a test API which sends me data from one or more tags in a SCADA/Historian system.   For one tag, I refresh the API call every 5 seconds and generate a simple ListPlot[] of this single current value.  The variable currentvalue is also to be stored in a growing list.

In the code below, I using the function AppendTo[]to add the dynamic variable to the list. In a grid, I plot the single point, give the single value, and provide the list.

However, the list never grows. The current value appended to the list dynamically updates whenever the value from the SCADA updates. But I cannot seem to append this new data to the list.  I would like to keep a history of the data that has been imported.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

````
Manipulate[
 
 Newvalue = 0;
 OldValue = 0;
 currentvalue = 0;
 HydrateList2 = {};
 
 currentvalue = Dynamic[Refresh[
                            
    URLExecute[
         "http://LAPTOP-QC9NCDI2:55235/api/v2/getTagData", {"tags" -> 
           "LAPTOP-XXXXX.GBXXXField.Sine.Tag0001" 
                    }][[3]][[2]][[1]][[2]],
                        UpdateInterval -> 5]];(*Find the correct spot in array*)
 
 NewValue = currentvalue[[1]][[2]][[2]];(*Extracting numerical value*)
 
 
 (*If[NewValue\[NotEqual]OldValue,
                ArrValue=NewValue;
                AppendTo[HydrateList2,N[ArrValue]];
                OldValue=ArrValue;
            ,""
            ];*)
 
 AppendTo[HydrateList2, NewValue];
 
 Grid[{{ ListPlot[{{1, NewValue}}, ImageSize -> 400], NewValue, 
    HydrateList2}}],
 
 
 TrackedSymbols -> {currentvalue},
 Paneled -> False
 ]
```
````

Comment: I cannot run your code, but if you just want to repeat an operation every 5 seconds, it seems to me that using a `ScheduledTask` is more appropriate than `Manipulate`. I mean, I had never seen a Manipulate with no controls.

Comment: Also, you are setting `currentvalue` to the output of `Dynamic` which is not what you want. You probably want to set it to the output of `URLExecute`.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino. Thanks, I will give it a shot moving the work out of a manipulate.  Also, thanks for the clarification on the URLExecute

Comment: @GustavoDelfino, Just wanted to give some feedback.  I removed the manipulate went with `ScheduledTask` and it worked well.  Thanks for the advise